# How do I pass multiple return value to a laravel controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I wan't to pass multiple variable to a laravel controller using ajax that has multiple return value.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  var standard = standardRoom();
  var n_standard = standard[0];
  var xSumStandard = standard[1];
  var totalStandard = standard[2];

  var quad = quadRoom();
  var n_quad = quad[0];
  var xSumQuad = quad[1];
  var totalQuad = quad[2];

  var family = familyRoom();
  var n_family = family[0];
  var xSumFamily = family[1];
  var totalFamily = family[2];

  var barkada = barkadaRoom();
  var n_barkada = barkada[0];
  var xSumBarkada = barkada[1];
  var totalBarkada = barkada[2];

    $('#formSubmit').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
           url: APP.baseUrl + '/check/next',
           data: {'_token': window.Laravel.csrfToken, 'n_standard': n_standard, 'xSumStandard': xSumStandard, 'totalStandard': totalStandard,'n_quad': n_quad,'xSumQuad': xSumQuad,'totalQuad': totalQuad,'n_family': n_family,'xSumFamily': xSumFamily,'totalFamily': totalFamily, 'n_barkada': n_barkada,'xSumBarkada': xSumBarkada,'totalBarkada': totalBarkada},
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (data) {
               console.log('Success')
             },
        });
    });
});
  {!! Form::open(['url' => '/request',  'id' => 'formSubmit']) !!}
   <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="NEXT" style="width:310px;background-color:#5d0b0b">
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I tried to follow an instruction on how to access multiple return value here in stack and come up with this. I don't know if this is working or not. But what I need is to just pass all the value that is in the data:

**Route**

```
Route::post('check/next', 'Reservation@getRequest');
```

Now what is the next step in this? How do I get this in the controller? I'm new to laravel and ajax so I'm having a hard time understanding this process
The problem is I'm getting an Undefined index: n_standard
**Edit**

**Controller**

```
public function getRequest(Request $request){
   $n_standard = $_GET['n_standard'];
   $xSumStandard = $_GET['xSumStandard'];
   $totalStandard = $_GET['totalStandard'];

   $n_quad = $_GET['n_quad'];
   $xSumQuad = $_GET['xSumQuad'];
   $totalQuad = $_GET['totalQuad'];

   $n_family = $_GET['n_family'];
   $xSumFamily = $_GET['xSumFamily'];
   $totalFamily = $_GET['totalFamily'];

   $n_barkada = $_GET['n_barkada'];
   $xSumBarkada = $_GET['xSumBarkada'];
   $totalBarkada = $_GET['totalBarkada'];
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Why put all your JS code ? We don't need it. What did you try in your controller ? What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: Edited. My problem is if this is the right way to do it

Comment: And I'm getting an Undefined index: n_standard

Comment: Your route is defined as `post` and you use `$_GET`. Although, use Laravel request to get parameters.

Comment: @VincentDecaux can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller, first of all you should replace **$_GET** to **$_POST / $_REQUEST** because your are sending data from ajax through **POST**.

or

You can also check, you are getting request value or not using below given code.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
public function getRequest(Request $request){
 $request->all()
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the Undefined index: n_standard

Comment: comment your other code and only write `$request->all()` in your controller function and check your result.

Comment: I'ts a blank page. What does it mean?

Comment: return $request->all() and check in your ajax response

Comment: Only the token {"_token":"thGluqtg5FUHjRgZ4TRd36TlrhhsgyQRCKJSuzV7"}

Comment: `n_standard ` have any value? could you please print before sending through ajax

Comment: For testing purpose, send static value like that {'_token': window.Laravel.csrfToken, 'n_standard': 'rei testing'}

Comment: I think the problem is in the variable. I'ts undefined

Comment: could you please mark given answer correct. thanks in advance.